# What sites are available to sell original boxes?

Tags: shopping, vintage, value, trading

A couple of years ago, I stumbled across a site (not Ebay) where LEGO fans buy and sell items.  I have some large boxes for various sets to sell.  All my son's LEGO collection is in plastic boxes, and I don't think he has any interest in keeping the boxes.  I also have all the original instructions, and noticed somebody talking about some really high prices.

Can any of you refer me to a good site for selling, other than Ebay?

I do sell on Ebay (going through closets and such as awe downsize), but I figured these would be more interesting to LEGO collectors.

Answer (score 12):

You probably came across **[BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/)**.

They sell pretty much anything LEGO related, including [original boxes](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=O) and [instruction books](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=I).

Comment: Definitely Bricklink, specify "Box Only"; but I'm not sure whether that has a lot of success (depends on the set I suppose). Then again, I'm more of the keeps-the-bricks side than the keeps-the-box one.

Comment: Gosh, people even sell the [opened poly-bags](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=79754). Craziness.

Comment: Well, they *try to* - notice there is no "[Price Guide Info](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?O=8031-1)" on that one, which means it hasn't been sold yet, while a the box of an UCS Yoda has been sold [last december for 29.99€](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogPG.asp?O=7194-1)... Okay, time to raid my attic I guess...

Comment: Meh, I never keep the boxes once I've built the models, clearly a tad foolish ;).

Comment: Thanks, guys.  Another mom told me her method of keeping track of systems, which is the one I adopted:  Cut off the front of the box and discard the rest of the box.  I sure wish I had NOT followed her way of doing things.  I do have a few of the large boxes still intact, and all of the instruction manuals are in mint condition.  Off to Bricklink!

Comment: Hu-oh... it looks like I'm won't be able to sell my empty UCS Yoda boxes - they are, in fact, not empty.